# What should I do on the button to run my python script

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is the code which is working fine. The problem is I have made a virtual environment to run my python file. So, I have made a button, so when onClick I am calling the main.py file(There are other python files imported in this file) the problem is when I am clicking on the Click Me! button then it is opening my python script in Pycharm. What should I do?

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import sys

window=Tk()

window.title("Vehicular Monitoring System")
window.geometry('550x200')

def run():
    os.system('helmet.py')


B = Button(window, text ="Click Me!",command=run)

B.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

After clicking the button the module should execute instead of opening in Pycharm.

Comment: You can run it through shell, using `os.system('python helmet.py')`.

Comment: Can you also supply a trivial `helmet.py` script to illustrate the problem?  There is something in your environment or code that makes PyCharm the default interpreter.  I don't see anything here that should cause that problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vasilis G. It is working great..

Comment: VasilisG's comment (and alec_a's revised answer) may workaround the problem, but I think the root cause is due to what @Prune mentioned—that .py files have somehow been associated with PyCharm. How that is accomplished depends on your OS, which you don't mention.

Comment: Hi martineau, yes the thing is as default the python files are associated with Pycharm. But i was confused that if i am giving any command then why it is opening Pycharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.system("command")` passes the command, with any arguments, to your system's shell. So

```
os.system("python helmet.py -any args")  # you don't need any arguments
```

will work